# How can this boolean expression be simplified?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I would like to have a step-by-step simplification of this boolean expression
$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}+\bar{x}\bar{y}z\bar{w}+\bar{x}yz\bar{w}+\bar{x}yzw+x\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}+x\bar{y}z\bar{w}+x\bar{y}zw+xy\bar{z}w+xyzw? $

I have done:

$\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{w}(\bar{z}+z)+\bar{x}yz(\bar{w}+w)+x\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}+x\bar{y}z(\bar{w}+w)+xyz(\bar{w}+w)=$
$=\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{w}+\bar{x}yz+x\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}+x\bar{y}z+xyz=$

$=xyz+x\bar{y}z+\bar{x}yz+\bar{y}\bar{w}(\bar{x}+x\bar{z})$

But I don't know how to reduce furthermore

Comment: What is $x$ and $\overline{x}$?

Comment: is like NOT x, or x!

Comment: What have you done yourself sofar?

Comment: Let me get you started $\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}+\bar{x}\bar{y}z\bar{w}=\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{w}(\bar{z}+z)=\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{w}$.

Comment: Two basic approaches here [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) or [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  Lets see your effort first.

Comment: @Mathematics1990   Here is a mistake (end of the first part) $\bar{x}\bar{y}\bar{w}(\bar{z}+z)+\bar{x}yz(\bar{w}+w)+x\bar{y}\bar{z}\bar{w}+x\bar{y}z(\bar{w}+w)+{\color{red}{xyz(\bar{w}+w)}}=$